# GWT [WARN] 404 upon trying to GET image

Tags: image, gwt, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to upload an image to a site I'm creating via GWT. The site does not load at all. In the console, I get this error message:
[WARN] 404 - GET /bodyheatmap/img/heart2.png (127.0.0.1) 1412 bytes

Here are the lines of relevant code:
        final Image heart = new Image(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() +"img/heart2.png");
        RootPanel.get("pictureContainer").add(heart);

Currently I'm working in eclipse, and within my bodyheatmap directory I have a folder, "img," with heart2.png.

Comment: _"within my bodyheatmap directory I have a folder, "img," with heart2.png"_ Which bodyheatmap directory? where is it located? If you use getModuleBaseURL, your img directory should be in a 'public' folder within your GWT module's package.

Comment: i'm guessing bodyheatmap is his app id.

Comment: Thomas, I believe that's what I have. GWT.getModuleBaseUrl() returned "/bodyheatmap," giving the correct path.  I tried the exact thing on my mac running on firefox--it worked. Tried on Windows, chrome--does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put those files into the war directory.
Also `new Image("img/heart2.png"), i.e. a relative link, should work just as well.

Finally, you should have a look at [ClientBundles](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#ImageResource)

Comment: I tried both putting the 'img' folder in the war directory and putting the .png file directly in the war directory, changing the URL correspondingly. It didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: check the case of your filename or if you've made another typo(e.g. / vs. \ )